# Mocha Run Configuration in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, mocha.js

I have configured mocha to run testcases in my react app via mocha intelliJ mocha plugin , i have defined the configuration as below :

[image]

I have helper Javascript file which is suppose to be loaded by mocha before test hence i added --config in mocha option in above screenshot and the content of that file is below :

```
--recursive
--require helper.js
```

Issue is it seems like this helper is not loading hence i am getting errors like :

```
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
 windows is not defined
```

where in the windows is defined in helper.js hence my issue is how to load helper.js from mocha run configuration present in intelliJ

Alternative to this when i run below command in terminal this works fine and hence runs all test cases in terminal for mocha :

```
mocha --require babel-register --require ignore-styles --require ./test/test.helper.js
```

but i want to run single test from intelliJ only hence any pointers to this issue is greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

The right way to pass `mocha.opts` to mocha is `--opts` option, like `--opts config/mocha.opts` (path has to be relative to project root folder). The path to the local module in `mocha.opts` should also be relative to the project root. 
For example, if my helper is located in `<project dir>/specs/util/test.helper.js`, and `mocha.opts` - in `<project dir>/config/mocha.opts`, `.opts` would be

```
--require ./specs/util/test.helper.js
```

and run configuration would look as follows:

[image]